# React js Performance tool addon throws "Cannot read property 'counts' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs

I've confused as to how to utilize React's performance tool. My current usage is shown below:

```
var Perf = React.addons.Perf;
Perf.start();
this.setState({
    newState: newStateObject,
}, function(){
    Perf.printInclusive();
    Perf.stop();
});
```

This doesn't render anything on the page and blurts out

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'counts' of undefined
```

Comment: Try calling first `Perf.stop()` and then `Perf.printInclusive()`. Also you should post here whole traceback.

Comment: Switching the order didn't make a difference. log screenshot: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yp4la5u3rwjkai0/Screen%20Shot%202014-12-04%20at%2010.48.40%20AM.png?dl=0

Comment: Are you sure this issue is triggered by Perf? In your error message nothing indicates to it. Do you output `counts` value somewhere in HTML?

Comment: Each of the perf summary functions call for a measurements.count. Measurements seem to be undefined.

Comment: did you solve this issue?  I'm seeing the same thing.  Here's the code.   https://gist.github.com/joshuacalloway/ae5b184c485956314d1c

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3389#issuecomment-79236067.

It looks like `Perf.start()` only works if it is called outside of the component lifecycle. So, call it before you start your application, or call it directly from the browser's console before you trigger the event you're trying to monitor.

Comment: Hope they improve the documentation on this. Not an easy thing to find.

Comment: why it prints undefined after I called 'Perf.start()' in the console?

Answer (score 1):

Your error stack trace seems to be coming from something else...

First of all you first need to call `Perf.stop()` and then try calling `printInclusive()`. It won't print anything on the page, it should spit out a nice table into the browser's console.

However, the easiest way to try Perf Tools is to open your browser's console and type it in manually `window.React.addons.Perf.start();` followed by your actions and eventually `window.React.addons.Perf.stop();` and `window.React.addons.Perf.printExclusive();` or whichever API call you're using.

Comment: Could you tell me what I am doing wrong , when I call window.React.addons.Perf.start() at the console , I get the error Cannot read property 'addons' of undefined(…),  Thanks for any advice

Comment: Hey @Davet, please make sure that you are using the right React version. Out-of-the-box React comes without the addons. Check the [this page](https://facebook.github.io/react/downloads.html) and make sure you're including `<script src="https://fb.me/react-with-addons-0.13.3.js"></script>`. Let me know if it works?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Perf.start() should put outside of render, so I add  Perf.stop() in render callback function.

code below, hope it can be helpful:)

```
Perf.start();

ReactDOM.render(
    <App  />,
  document.getElementById('app'),()=>{
    Perf.stop();
    var measurements = Perf.getLastMeasurements();
    console.table(Perf.getLastMeasurements());
    Perf.printInclusive(measurements);
    Perf.printExclusive(measurements);
    Perf.printWasted(measurements);
    Perf.printDOM(measurements);
  }
);
```